# Run Test Method miltiple times with different testdata using just anotations

Tags: java, junit, testng, testng-annotation-test

I would like to run the test method multiple times and during each of test runs, I want initialise method to be run with different parameters for the RestApiCall.sendRequest() method say a,b,c and d. Also I want the test method to print the testname as per the parameter passed.

```
@BeforeaClass
void initialise(){
   ResponseData responsedata = RestApi.sendRequest("a");
}

@Test
void TestApiCall(){
  testResponse(responsedata);
  System.out.println("Passed TestApiCall A");
}
```

Comment: if i have understood correctly, then, you have a set of test cases, and iterate with tests

Answer (score 0):

There are totally two ways of doing this.

**Approach #1: Using a data provider powered factory**

Here you have a `@Factory` that is powered by a data provider, to have test classes instances to be created and within that, you can have a `@BeforeMethod` do whatever rest call invocation you need to do and then have your `@Test` method work with the response.

Here's a full fledged sample that shows this

```java
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClassUsingFactory {

  private final String parameter;

  @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
  public SampleTestClassUsingFactory(String parameter) {
    this.parameter = parameter;
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
    //Include your code to fire your Rest Call here
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    System.err.println("Using the parameter " + parameter);
  }

  @DataProvider(name = "dp")
  public static Object[][] getTestData() {
    return new Object[][]{
        {"a"},
        {"b"},
        {"c"}
    };
  }
}
```

**Approach #2: Using a data provider powered test method**

In this you have your `@Test` method powered by a data provider and within your `@BeforeMethod` you intercept the parameters being passed to the `@Test` method and do your rest call initialisation inside it.

Here's a sample that shows that in action

```java
public class SampleTestClassUsingDataProvider {

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod(ITestResult testResult) {
    Object[] parameters = testResult.getParameters();
    //Simulate as if we are doing something with the parameters array
    System.err.println("Parameters for the test method = " + Arrays.toString(parameters));
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void testMethod(String parameter) {
    System.err.println("Using the parameter " + parameter);
  }


  @DataProvider(name = "dp")
  public static Object[][] getTestData() {
    return new Object[][]{
        {"a"},
        {"b"},
        {"c"}
    };
  }

}
```

> Also I want the test method to print the testname as per the parameter
> passed.

You can have your test class implement the `org.testng.ITest` interface and have it give back a custom name, but it all boils down to the actual reporter that you are using and whether that is honouring this or not. Its going to be easy if you just implement your own `org.testng.IReporter` wherein you can have this customisation as needed